# Basic mysqli_connect errors

Tags: php

I am simply attempting to connect to my database. I have all the correct login and IP info, but I still keep getting an error. Im using HostGator for my hosting and Dreamweaver to develop. I've even reset my password just to make sure my login is correct. What am I not doing right to establish a connection with my database?  Thanks!

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 
'mlakes_1012'@'192.185.21.144' (using password: YES) in   
/home1/mlakes/public_html/index.php on line 28
Couldn’t connect to server.

<?php

$host= '192.185.21.144';
$user= 'mlakes_1012';
$password= '********';
$dbname = 'mlakes_wonsport';
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)
or die ("Couldn’t connect to server.");

mysqli_close($cxn);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$host` should be "`localhost`", not "`192.185.21.144`".  I noticed that you are trying to connect to MySQL locally, relative to the server you're on.

On cPanel shared hosting environments, "192.185.21.144" isn't recognized as a host for the user you have specified unless it is added in cPanel » Databases » Remote MySQL®.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
         $host= '192.185.21.144';
```

to

```
         $host = 'localhost';
```

and it will work